# Making my resource manager be "deadlock-free"

Tags: java, multithreading, resources

My program has a condition to be deadlock-free. 
The ResourceManager give clients in 
`(Set<ResourceNames, long ID>)`
 to write/read (boolean true/false). 
that is a method  `static long getLock(Set<String> resources, boolean operation)` 
and  `static void releaseLock(long ID)`.

All of the resource is 1-1. IfF the resource is engage for write, that resource is not applicable for another target. If for read, other clients can get for only read, write not.
The resource names is Strings.While the ResourceManager can not gice the resource for the client it has to block in the getlock() method and return when the resources are avaliable for the client.

The getlock() method is engage a resource, and create an ID, and the relaselock() method is emancipate the resources from ID. My task is to write the ResourceManager, and it will be Deadlock-free.

The Client class create k client for random operation and resources, and start this. That class is written, but i can't see it.
My task is to write a class, and these two methods.

-And the problem is to block the client and return!
-DeadLock - free

```
package itself.probafeladat14;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class ResourceManager {

    protected static HashMap<String, Boolean> reservedResources = 
            new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    protected static HashMap<Long, Set<String>> resourcesByID = 
            new HashMap<Long, Set<String>>();
    protected static LinkedList<Long> sequenceOfID =
            new LinkedList<Long>();



    public static void releaseLock(long ID) {
        boolean read = false;
        Set<String> resources = resourcesByID.remove(ID);
        sequenceOfID.remove(ID);

        for (String str : resources)
            if (reservedResources.containsKey(str)) {
                if (reservedResources.get(str) == true)
                    reservedResources.remove(str);
                else if (reservedResources.get(str) == false) {
                    for (long i : sequenceOfID)
                        if (resourcesByID.get(i).contains(str))
                            read = true;
                    if (!read)
                        reservedResources.remove(str);
                    read = false;
                }
            }
    }


    public static long getLock(Set<String> resources, boolean operation) throws ResourceNotAvaliableException {

        boolean isFree = true;
        boolean uniqueID = false;
        long ID = 0;

        for (String str : resources) {
            if (reservedResources.containsKey(str)) {
                if (reservedResources.get(str) ) {
                    isFree = false;
                }
                if (reservedResources.get(str) == false && 
                        operation == true) {
                    isFree = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( !isFree )
            throw new ResourceNotAvaliableException();
        else {
            for (String s : resources)
                if (!reservedResources.containsKey(s))
                    reservedResources.put(s, operation);
            while (!uniqueID) {
                ID = new Random().nextLong();
                if (!sequenceOfID.contains(ID))
                    uniqueID = true;
            }
            sequenceOfID.addLast(ID);
            resourcesByID.put(ID, resources);
            return ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you can get deadlocks with your current implementation, but there are a number of multithreading problems with it:

- non-atomic behaviour when acquired locks (e.g. if I try to acquire the lock for A, then try to acquire the locks for B and A at the same time, then this will fail, but then trying to acquire the lock for just B will also fail because the previous operation made an incorrect change to the state).
- locks acquired when they shouldn't be (e.g. 2 threads calling `getLock()` for the same resource can both succeed because of the window of time between checking whether your resource is locked and actually adding the resource to the set.
- `ConcurrentModificationException` being thrown unpredictably when 2 threads try to update the same non-thread-safe collection at the same time.

You can fix some of these problems by synchronizing certain methods, but you'll need to do this carefully to avoid deadlocks on the one hand and making it a parallelism bottleneck on the other hand.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) 
in the getLock method instead:

```
      if (!reservedResources.containsKey(s)) {
        reservedResources.get(s).set(operation);
      }
```

This will avoid locks as Simon says, and you will not need to use synchronized methods.

Also, I would do all the 'isFree' logic to the bottom of the method.
In other words:

```
     for (String s : resources) {
         if (reservedResources.containsKey(s)) {
             if (reservedResources.get(s).get()) {
                 throw new ResourceNotAvaliableException();
             }
             if (!reservedResources.get(s).get() && operation == true) {
                 throw new ResourceNotAvaliableException()
             }
         }
    }
    for (String s : resources) {
        if (!reservedResources.containsKey(s))
            reservedResources.put(s, operation);
    }
    while (!uniqueID) {
        ID = new Random().nextLong();
        if (!sequenceOfID.contains(ID))
            uniqueID = true;
    }
    sequenceOfID.addLast(ID);
    resourcesByID.put(ID, resources);
    return ID;
```